# How to test HAProxy different type of log

Tags: haproxy

I made a custom log format for my HAProxy and I would like to test it. I would like also to test errors rendered by HAProxy with the setting [`log-separate-errors`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#option%20log-separate-errors).

How could I generate error for HAProxy like errors, timeouts, retries, redispatches...?

I need to add triggers to my external logger when errors happen.